# Windows Explorer hacked, Restore files corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, malware

Not expecting a critter in a FB page, I clicked on it.  Instantly a new icon for "White Trader" appeared on my Desktop, a message about not using it "in long time" popped up, Dropbox loaded itself and updated itself(which I rarely, if ever, use) and Windows Explorer is unresponsive.  Task Manager didn't want to start, though I worked around that.  Malware Bytes and Housecall didn't locate it.  I'm running Kapersky now, so far it has revealed 6 malware infections.  I don't mind paying for the program to remove it...but I have no idea if what it has found is the cause of the problem.  I do have a clone copy of the C: drive on a separate partition of a different drive, but would rather not lose the updates on the original c:.  White Trader seems to be a legitimate options trading site, complete with live chat (and a friendly person on the other end.) using XP32, 3rd rev. Any suggestions?

Comment: The symptoms do not sound like those of a legitimate app. Use good anti-malware and anti-virus apps to clean your system after disconnecting it from the net. If you're unsure how deep the infection goes and don't want to take any chances, forget the OS updates, back up only your important data that's changed since you cloned the system and then restore your cloned image. Don't forget to scan any data you've backed up from the infected partition before restoring!

Comment: @MDVickery - If your unable to launch Task Manager then your system intrigity is in question.  I would run a `sfc /scannow ` and verify.

Comment: Thank you -I ran multiple scans, opened in safe mode and went digging through directories -win exp worked in safe.  Also ran a scan in safe mode.  Deleted the icon shortcut while in safe. Rebooted and when the critter tried to search for it, AVG snuffed it.  All works now, but I don't really trust that it is completely gone.  It acted like a trojan.click, but nothing would find it. I'll do a rootkit scrub next.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to physically disconnect yourself from the internet before doing this so as to prevent any malware gateways this virus might have.

You have a few options now:

1. Restore your computer to a time before the virus installed itself. This reverts any settings it may have changed in windows, in my experience this renders it inert so you can properly scan and remove it.
2. Run a virus scan on your entire computer. Use Kapersky TDSSKiller to find any rootkits that may be present
3. You mentioned you managed to get Task Manager open. Check for any malicious looking processes and right click and go to `Open File Location` End the process and try to delete the files associated with it (This is risky, make sure these processes aren't innocent) If the OS claims its in use, download and install Unlocker and unlock the file.

Without going to deep into detail, these are generally the three methods I have used in the past to rid myself of viruses that are tricky. All in all I never trust that the virus is completely gone. If successful, backup what you need and restore the clone you have of your C drive. For the future, consider having a separate drive or partition for files/applications that you want to preserve across windows installations so as not to forfeit things you wish to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue start 2 days ago

to resolve the Windows Explorer crashing, I was able to do a System Restore thanks to an automated point being created from a Flash Update (it was hidden until "show older restore points" box was checked), though a Restore Point I had created a few weeks ago had been deleted

To remove the malware involved, I googled '"White Trader" desktop' and followed [this thread](http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=127411)

the only step I used was downloading AdwCleaner, placing it on desktop, running as Administrator, running a search, and then cross referencing the results with the  AdwCleanerR1.txt that was posted

since everything listed looked similar, I chose the Delete option, and following the restart, problem was resolved

( a few Registry results that showed up uniquely on my scan were \Tracing\SnapDo and \Classes\CLISD)

(each of the Internet Browser results contained "feed.snap.do" in their names)

I do not know what the result of running AdwCleaner without the wow.dll issue being resolved would be, i.e. running a Norton Power Scan yielded no results other than pointing out wow64.dll for deletion, which seemed like a bad idea.

Also keep in mind that I'm by no means an expert, but hope this helps